# Silverlight modify hosting html page

Tags: html, silverlight, dom

Is there any way to modify an html page hosting a Silverlight page using the embedded Silverlight application?  I already know how to access existing html elements, but I'm not sure how to add and remove elements dynamically.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you got hold of an HtmlElement, use its API to add/remove an element, i.e. use the AppendChild, RemoveChild methods. Or set properties of an element with SetProperty. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlelement_members(v=VS.95).aspx) for the full API.

Comment: Okay, how would I do that for a <p></p> tag?  How would I get text in between the two tags?

Comment: Note that this is more a DOM question than a Silverlight one. Have a look at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/12022/39574.aspx or http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/silverlight-tutorial-interaction-with-the-dom, Changing the text of an element is done by setting the innerHTML property of this element. So, use p.SetProperty("innerHtml", "new value") once you got hold of the <p> element